# How can I filter a sheet to show only one instance of a particular substring?

Tags: sorting, google-sheets, concatenation, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-query

I have a spreadsheet where the values in a column are texts with some common patterns.

```
M03 D12
M03 D11
M04 D11
M02 D20
```

I'd like to filter this sheet so that I see only one appearance of a particular subtext instead of the whole text. For instance, by "M" and the number that follows.

```
M03 D11
M04 D11
M02 D20
```

Or by "D" and the number that follows.

```
M03 D12
M03 D11
M02 D20
```

I tried to use a custom function along the lines of `=COUNTIF(A2:A, "M03*")=1`. What this does is it filters out everything except the last occurrence of `M03`, as the range in `COUNTIF` is not fixed so the last occurrence of `M03` would be counted only once. The problem is that this works only for strings containing `M03`. I'd like to do this together with `M04`, `M02`, and any other subtext of my choosing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
=TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(SORTN(IFERROR(SPLIT(
 SORT(A:A, 1, 1), " ")), ROWS(A:A), 2, 1, 0)),,999^99))
```

[image: 0]

---

```
=TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(SORTN(IFERROR(SPLIT(
 SORT(A:A, 1, 1), " ")), ROWS(A:A), 2, 2, 1)),,999^99))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Looks like this works but it looks really complicated